# Why do i get no formatted result (csv) with my xsl?

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

How can i give my output the correct format? What is missing in the XSLT?
Look at my example below. Thank you in advance for your help.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FED xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <POI>
      <Id>56241</Id>
      <POI_Contact>
         <CategoryID>museum</CategoryID>
         <Name>Centre Pompidou</Name>
      </POI_Contact>
  </POI>
   <POI>
      <Id>141670</Id>
      <POI_Contact>
         <CategoryID>museum</CategoryID>
         <Name>Espace Culturel Saint-Exupéry</Name>
      </POI_Contact>
   </POI>
   <POI>
      <Id>56242</Id>
      <POI_Contact>
         <CategoryID>museum</CategoryID>
         <Name>Musée du Louvre</Name>
      </POI_Contact>
  </POI>
</FED>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">

ID;Category;Name

  <xsl:for-each select="FED/POI">     
    <xsl:value-of select="Id"/>;
    <xsl:value-of select="POI_Contact/CategoryID"/>
  </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
   ID;Category;Name
   56241;
    museum
141670;
    museum
56242;
    museum
```

The output should look like this:

ID;Category;Name
  56241;museum
  141670;museum
  56242;museum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with specifying  literal text like you have is that the entire text node, including the surrounding white spaces, is passed to the output.

Try instead:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>ID;Category;Name&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="FED/POI">     
        <xsl:value-of select="Id"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="POI_Contact/CategoryID"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

---

P.S. Your header says `ID;Category;Name`, but you are not outputting the `Name`.